# BlueJ call to public method null pointer exception (java.awt.container)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bluej

Normally I would instantiate the panels inside of the makeFrame method, but instead I'm required to use two separate methods of CreateButtonPanel() and createTextPanel(). The problem being that I cannot work out how to let makeFrame use these when they are not inside of it's own method, and when I'm used to JavaScript what I've done looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: Please include enough source code to produce a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than linking a screenshot.

Comment: Also post the stacktrace you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot, you are creating a local variable in the `createButtonPanel` method making it unavailable (null) to the `add` method of the container.

```
public void createButtonPanel()
{
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
}
```

Instead, make it assign the new instance to the class level variable so that it won't be null when passing into the `add` method of the container.

```
public void createButtonPanel()
{
    this.buttonPanel = new JPanel(); // Now we are assigning to the class member
}
```

This should fix your problem. Also, it is advised that you move this to a initializer method that your constructor calls and make it `private` as there is no use of making it `public` in this case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that makes sense. I have worked with (this.) before as a way to return values back to the objects declared at the top of my code, but did not consider that it would return it to the method for use with others that it has been called from.

Comment: Rephrase it Ryan, I don't think you understood clearly, there is nothing here with returning a value.